# Typescript - Update object properties dynamically with Object.entries

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I want to implement a function that loops over the properties of an object and applies updates to another object of the same type.

```
interface Car {
  tires: number;
  name: string;
}

function updateCar(car: Car, updates: Partial<Car>) {
  Object.entries(updates).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    car[key] = value;
  })
}
```

The issue here is that there is an error

```
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Car'
```

when casting the key to `keyof Car` it works, but as soon as using `"noImplicitAny": true` there is again an error

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

Is there a way to solve this issue in a type-safe matter. Casting the car to any would work but I'd like to avoid it.

Many thanks
Bene

Comment: `Partial<Car>` would allow me to pass `{tires: 4, name: undefined}`. Do you want that?

Comment: @AluanHaddad - the question is just targeted to the typing problem. I know that this method has some caveats and some other checks would be necessary but this is not the scope of my question :)

Comment: Yes but I am trying to point out that they are related. If you just want a way to do it that won't complain, use `Object.assign(car, updates)`

Answer (score 16):

This question inspired me to revisit a similar problem I ran into.

While not a direct analog of your problem (i.e. this is a pure function that returns a `new` object rather than modifying arguments supplied by the caller), here's an update function that retains type-safety by using object-spread instead of the `Object.entries()` function to do its work:

```
function updateFromPartial<T>(obj: T, updates: Partial<T>):T { 
    return {...obj, ...updates}; 
}
```

Comment: Note that this returns a new object rather than updating in-place

Comment: Great! I wasn't aware `Partial` exist :)

Comment: Thank you for this, spent days without figuring something out.

Answer (score 4):

That function already exists. Why not just use?

```
Object.assign(car, updates);
```

> The Object.assign() method copies all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It returns the modified target object. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: It seems like `Object.assign` is not type checked, which means you can affect anything to `car`. For example if you `Car` type has a `color: string` but you update object comes with `{color: null}` this line of code will not raise any error (eventhough it should).

Answer (score 3):

This is about as typesafe as I could get it. The only thing left not properly typed is `car[key]`. This is clearly not a perfect solution.

```
interface Car {
  tires: number;
  name: string;
}

function updateCar(car: Car, updates: Partial<Car>) {
    for (const update in updates) {
        const key = update as keyof Car;
        (car[key] as any) = updates[key];
    }
}
```